# How to embed a Google Docs form in a Google Sites page?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, google-classic-sites

I tried copying the iframe code to the page but the form does not display. Instead a box is down that does not contain the form:

[image]

What is the right way to embed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Inserting Google Docs, Spreadsheets, Presentations, and Forms**
>
> You can embed Google Documents, Spreadsheets, Presentations, and Forms
>   into your Google Site in two simple steps:
>
> - Click the  “Edit page” button to open the site editor.
> - Place the cursor where you would like to insert the object.
> - From the Insert menu, select the object you wish to insert.
>
> Note: The inserted object will be view-only to the public. However,
>   when the contents of the objects are updated at its source and
>   published, it is updated automatically within your site.
>
> Anyone with collaborator access to your site will be able to view a
>   link under each embedded object that will allow them to pop out an
>   editable version of the object.

[Taken from this Google Help Article](http://www.google.com/support/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=90569)

Answer (score 1):

Embedding doesn't work on Internet Explorer even if you do it correctly
Will work on all other browsers however the default security level on the newer versions of IE will not show embedded Google Docs.  There is no work around outside of getting each user to go to their security settings and changing it to 'Low" which is not pratical